# install python reddit api wrapper module

Tags: python, api, module, wrapper, reddit

I have downloaded the source in a zip file. I then moved it to /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mellort-reddit_api-2d91358. I have been trying to install it with: python setup.py install. This has not worked. I then tried to install it with python /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mellort-reddit_api-2d91358/setup.py install, but that would not work as well.

On both occasions it said:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mellort-reddit_api-2d91358/setup.py", line 9,     in         <module>
    open('reddit/__init__.py').read()).group(1)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'reddit/__init__.py'
```

I think it cannot find the:

```
reddit/__init__.py
```

I have only tried putting the file in the python 2.6 folder.

Any thoughts? If you could provide step by step instructions I would be extremely happy.
I am using mac if that makes a difference.

If you have used this module before (found at https://github.com/mellort/reddit_api) how did  you deal with this issue?

Comment: I literally put the error message in the post. I suggest you get eyeglasses sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install it through `pip`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential
sudo pip install reddit -U
```

**update after OP's comments:**

for a mac you can do this:

```
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install reddit -U
```

more info on how to install pip on a mac can be found [here](http://www.pidby.com/2009/07/installing-pip-and-ipython-on-mac.html).

Comment: does this work for mac and can you try this, if you have a mac, too make sure it works?